# How Can I get to the count to show count for zip that has 0 count

Tags: sql

Below is my query I need show Zip codes with zero count

Select`propertyzip as Zip, Zip.city as City, zip.fips as Fips, Propertystate as state, Count(*) as Total From dbo.proplistsource a, Zipcode.dbo.zip Zip, Zipcode.dbo.cnty where cnty.fips = zip.fips   and zip.zip = a.propertyzip  and zip.ll = 'L' and Propertyzip in ('37849', '37909',  '37914', '37918',  '37921',  '37923', '37931')  and a.propid in (Select max(propid)     from dbo.proplistsource b   where b.Propertyzip in ('37849', '37909',  '37914',  '37918',  '37921',  '37923', '37931')  and propertyusestandardized in ('181')) group by    propertyzip,   zip.City,    zip.Fips,   Propertystate`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the sql directly as text. That will help the community help you. Thanks.

Comment: Desired Resullt   ZIP CITY FIPS COUNTY STATE TOTAL
37849 POWELL                       47093 KNOX                      TN 114
37909 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 27
37914 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 0
37918 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 118
37921 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 114
37923 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 0
37931 KNOXVILLE                    47093 KNOX                      TN 53
Total     426

Comment: @SwetaWalker, still missing code.  What you have put in comment section should be pasted into question.

Comment: @SwetaWalker.. check out the following userprofile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff. If Gordon adds the '!' and he doesn't mention you should poste your code as text... you're very lucky. But removing the edit... Ooh boy... Now you realy should add your scripting text (as code; there is a button for it). Enjoy SO ;p

Comment: @Eray Balkanli having count(*)  < 1 is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `having` clause at the bottom, like:

```
...<your query>...
having count(*) < 1
```